# Say I have 9 elements, five of which are 0's and four of which are 1's, how many combinations are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I'm trying to optimise a search algorithm for some code I'm writing, and need some mathematical help.
So for example 000001111 is a different combination to 000010111, but at all times the ratio of 0's to 1's must be maintained, how many combinations are there?

By extension how would I generalise this so that I could change the total number of starting elements and the distribution. For example, I can input into some formula that there are now 20 elements, with a 12/8 split between the two different types of element.

Comment: Are you content to be able to figure out that there are 126 such permutations? Or do you need some way to index/enumerate them?

Comment: @Servaes  That is a different question.  This question is about choosing the positions of the zeros in a binary string.

Comment: @2'59'2 That would be great actually. Do you know a simple way of indexing/enumerating them?

Answer (score 1):

Basically out of the $9$ positions, you need to select $5$ positions in which $0$ will be placed.
So, the answer is $9C5=126$

Comment: In general, if you want to place $a$ elements of type $1$ and $b$ elements of type $2$ into $a+b$ positions, the number of such combinations will be $(a+b)Ca=\frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$

Comment: Ohhh that's a much smarter way of looking at the problem! Thinking of each position as a distinct element to choose from. I was trying to figure out some permutation thing involving repetitions. Thanks!

Comment: But this approach would only work when there's two types of elements, right? Purely out of curiosity, what if there are 3 distinct types of elements, how much more complicated does that make the problem?

Comment: @Scott If you have more than two different types of elements in your string and you know how many of each type of element are in the string, you can use a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) to count the number of strings.  The multinomial coefficient reduces to a binomial coefficient when there are only two types of elements in the string.

Answer (score 0):

In the comment thread:

> Do you know a simple way of indexing/enumerating them?

As already posted in an answer, we know ahead of time how many of these there are. With $n$ bits where $k$ of them are $1$s, there are $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ permutations of the $1$s among the $0$s. (In the specific case of $n=9,k=4$, that works out to $126$.)

How can you index these? Meaning, can there be some canonical ordering of these permutations such that when you want say the $37$th one, you have a quick way to get it? Well, there is a canonical ordering: just view each one as a binary number. So the smallest is $000001111$ and the largest is $111100000$ and somewhere in the middle is $001011100$ (for example).

With this ordering, how do you quickly identify (for example) the $37$th one? I'll describe the logic focusing on finding the $37$th one, and you could translate it into a generic algorithm that finds the $j$th permutation one bit at a time. Among the $126$ permutations, there is a $\frac{5}{9}$ chance that the first bit is a $0$. So we have a benchmark index: $\frac{5}{9}(126)=70$. If a permutation's index is less than or equal to $70$, the first bit is $0$; otherwise it is $1$. But we are hunting the one with index $37<70$, so we have a $0$: $$0\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

Now $70$ permutations remain to consider. And $\frac{4}{8}$ of them have first bit $0$, so we set another benchmark: $\frac{4}{8}(70)=35$. This time $37$ is greater. So we have:$$01\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot{}$$

Now $35$ permutations remain to consider. But they are permutations in the interval $\{36,\cdots,70\}$, so in that context we need to readjust our "index 37" down to index $2$. Now $\frac{4}{7}$ of these have first bit $0$, so we set another benchmark: $\frac{4}{7}(35)=20$. And $2$ is less than that. So another $0$ bit. We have:$$010\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot{}$$

Now $20$ permutations remain to consider. And $\frac{3}{6}$ of them have first bit $0$, so we set another benchmark: $\frac{3}{6}(20)=10$. And $2$ is still below the benchmark, so another $0$:$$0100\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot{}$$

Now $10$ permutations remain to consider. And $\frac{2}{5}$ of them have first bit $0$, so we set another benchmark: $\frac{2}{5}(10)=4$. And $2$ is still below the benchmark, so another $0$:$$01000\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot{}$$

Now $4$ permutations remain to consider. And $\frac{1}{4}$ of them have first bit $0$, so we set another benchmark: $\frac{1}{4}(4)=1$. This time $2$ is greater, so we have a $1$. And we will have to reset our "index 2" to be "index 1" among $\{2,3,4\}$. $$010001\cdot\cdot\cdot{}$$

Now $3$ permutations remain to consider. And $\frac{1}{3}$ of them have first bit $0$, so we set another benchmark: $\frac{1}{3}(3)=1$. And $1$ is right there, so a $0$:$$0100010\cdot\cdot{}$$

Finally $2$ permutations remain to consider. But $\frac{0}{2}$ of them have first bit $0$. All remaining bits are $1$: $$010001011$$

And that is our $37$th such permutation among the $\binom{9}{4}$ permutations, ordered as binary numbers.

---

You can use the same reasoning to go the other way. Say you have one of these permutations, for example $001011100$, and you want to know its index. That leading $0$ tells us it is in $\{1,...,70\}$. Then another $0$, so we are in $\{1,\ldots,35\}$.

But then a $1$. At this point with the lead $00$ accounted for, there should be a $\frac{3}{7}$ chance of the next digit being a $0$. But it is a $1$. So we calculate $\frac{3}{7}(35)=15$, and our index is *not* in the lower $15$ of $\{1,\ldots,35\}$. That is, now we know the index is $\{16,\ldots,35\}$.

At this point, there should be a $\frac{3}{6}$ chance the next bit is $0$. And it was indeed a $0$. So we calculate $\frac{3}{6}(20)=10$ and we know we are in the lower $10$ of $\{16,\ldots,35\}$. That is, we are in $\{16,\ldots,25\}$.

The next three bits of my example are $1$s, so I'm going to cut to the chase and declare that we had the permutation with index $25$, the highest one left in are narrowed-down set.

---

Both of these processes can be coded algorithmically to work for generic $n$, $k$, and either a given index $j$ (to find a specific permutation) or a given permutation (to find a specific index $j$).

Comment: You have $9$ distinct elements $\{0_a, 0_b,0_c, 0_d, 0_e, 1_f, 1_g, 1_h,1_i\}$, (distinct is always useful). You have $9!$ ways to organize these 9 elements. But $0_a, 0_b,0_c, 0_d, 0_e$ are considered as similar, so we need to divide by $5!$, and same for $1_f, 1_g, 1_h,1_i$, we need to divide by $4!$ ; so the final number of combinations is $\frac{9!}{4!5!}$

Comment: @Lourrran That sounds like an answer to OP's question and you should post it as an answer. The answer here is mostly to a follow-up question in the comments. OP is writing code for a "search algorithm" so it seemed likely that actually indexing the $\frac{9!}{4!5!}$ options could be useful.